# Redirect all to index stuck on redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine       on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

currently redirect all to index and strips trailing slash. but when there is sub-folder with the same name with URL will end up in redirect loop

I've tried searching on Google but no luck. can someone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine       on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

i.e. don't rewrite to `index.php` if request if for a valid file or directory.

Comment: still end up in redirect loop :(

Comment: Comment out `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` and retest.